# How to create multiple scrollable full-view-height webpages in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

So I was using multiple `div` containers with height of 100vh to create a scrollable landing page. But the more `div` I add the first `div` height gets reduced and eventually disappears from the browser and only the pages at the bottom (pages 3, 4, 5) show up

**The Container React Component**

```
import React from "react";
import Page1 from "./Page1";
import Page2 from "./Page2";
import Page3 from "./Page3";
import Page4 from "./Page4";
import Page5 from "./Page5";

const Main = () => {
    return (
      <div className="Main">
        <Page1 />
        <Page2 />
        <Page3 />
        <Page4 />
        <Page5 />
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default Main;
```

**Each Page**

```
import React from "react";

const Page = () => {
  return (
    <div className="pagenumber" id="page">
      Page Text page number
    </div>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

**The Styling**
all pages have the same id so

```
#page{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.page1{
    background-color: red;
}
.page2{
    background-color: orange;
}
.page3{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.page4{
    background-color: lime;
}
.page5{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Where is the css for `.Main` and `body`?

Comment: ok I specified the body width to 100%, I see the problem now. thank you and sorry for the dumb question